# Find maximum element from two arrays

Tags: java

I need to find maximum element from two arrays

```
int arr1[]={20,65,23056,67,678};

int arr2[]={76,23,4545,98,90909};
```

My code is giving output but i think it's complexity is high.Below are my code.Is it good or it need improvement?

```
    int arr1[]={20,65,23056,67,678};
    int arr2[]={76,23,4545,98,90909};
    int len1=arr1.length;
    int len2=arr2.length;
    int max1=arr1[0];
    for(int i=0;i<len1;i++){
        if(arr1[i]>max1){
            max1=arr1[i];
        }

    }
    int max2=arr2[0];
    for(int j=0;j<len2;j++){
        if(arr2[j]>max2){
            max2=arr2[j];
        }

    }
    if(max1>max2){
        System.out.print("max element is:"+max1);
    }
    else{
        System.out.print("Max element is: "+max2);
    }
```

Output  :- 90909

Comment: What the problem here? nothing wrong your code.

Comment: One possible improvement: make a method to find the max element of an array, and then call that method two times, for both your arrays - that way you can avoid copy-and-pasting the code to find the max element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you don't want to deal with streams, you can still improve it a bit:

````java
int arr1[] = { 20, 65, 23056, 67, 678 };
int arr2[] = { 76, 23, 4545, 98, 90909 };

int len = arr1.length > arr2.length ? arr1.length : arr2.length;
int max = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if (arr1.length > i && arr1[i] > max) {
        max = arr1[i];
    }
    if (arr2.length > i && arr2[i] > max) {
        max = arr2[i];
    }
}

System.out.print("max element is:" + max);```
````

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
  Integer arr1[]={20,65,23056,67,678};

  Integer arr2[]={76,23,4545,98,90909};

  Integer max = Stream.concat(Arrays.stream(arr1), Arrays.stream(arr2)).max(Comparator.comparing(Integer::valueOf)).get();
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use Java streams to achieve this. If you want to avoid boxing values to `Integer` and you want to get primitive integer directly use [`IntStream::concat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#concat(java.util.stream.IntStream,java.util.stream.IntStream)) and and [`IntStream::of`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#of(int...)) :

```
int[] arr1 = {20, 65, 23056, 67, 678};
int[] arr2 = {76, 23, 4545, 98, 90909};

int max = IntStream
            .concat(IntStream.of(arr1), IntStream.of(arr2))
            .max()
            .getAsInt();
```

Answer (score 0):

If we consider the length of the first and second arrays as n and m respectively. Your solution is taking the complexity of O(n+m). It's the best case, as the arrays are not sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers here focus on Streams (which is perfectly fine - and acceptable).

However, if you have limitations on usage of stream (JDK 7 and earlier), you could put the arrays in a `TreeSet` with  `Collections.reverseOrder` to sort the elements in descending order. The `0th` index will be the largest or mac element from the union of the arrays.

Edit: Note that `TreeSet` doesn't persist duplicates, so you're better off than storing duplicates in arrays. In the worst case, if two arrays of `5 elements` each contained `9 duplicates`, the `TreeSet` would only house `2 elemens` (the unique one and the other being the duplicate one), as against two arrays containing `10 elements`.